# respond_to? and protected methods

Tags: ruby, encapsulation, access-specifier

It may not be so obvious how respond_to? works in ruby.
Consider that:

```
class A

   def public_method
   end

   protected
   def protected_method
   end

   private
   def private_method
   end

end

obj = A.new
obj.respond_to?(:public_method)
# true - that's pretty obvious
obj.respond_to?(:private_method)
# false - as expected
obj.respond_to?(:protected_method)
# true - WTF?
```

So if 'obj' responds to protected_method we should expect

```
obj.protected_method
```

not to raise an exception, shouldn't we?

...but it raises obviously

Documentation points that calling respond_to? with 2nd argument set to true check private method as well

```
obj.respond_to?(:private_method, true)
# true
```

And that's far more reasonable

So the question is how to check if object responds to public method only?
Is there a solution better than that?

```
obj.methods.include?(:public_method)
# true
obj.methods.include?(:protected_method)
# false
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is under debate if `respond_to?` should look for protected methods or not (check [this issue](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3562))

Matz has stated that it will probably change in Ruby 2.0.

Note some classes might use `#method_missing` and specialize `#respond_to?` (or better by  specify a `#respond_to_missing?` in Ruby 1.9.2+), in which case your `obj.methods.include?` will not be reliable.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand translated Japanese but anyway good to know that ruby core consider that issue. At least one may use obj.class.public_method_defined?(:protected_method) and it works as expected but won't handle singleton methods, so I rather consider that as workaround not real solution

Answer (score 12):

From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/respond_to%253F):

> Returns true if obj responds to the given method. Private **and
>     protected methods** are included in the search only if the optional
>     second parameter evaluates to true

When the question was written (Ruby 1.8.7):

> Returns true if obj responds to the given method. Private methods are included in the search only if the optional second parameter evaluates to true.

Comment: The question is from 2010. Back then in Ruby 1.8.7 the docs stated that: "Returns true> if obj responds to the given method. Private methods are included in the search only if the optional second parameter evaluates to true."

Comment: Still a valuable answer. I just discovered this curious bug when upgrading an old project from Ruby `1.8.7` to Ruby `2.1.1`.

Comment: It is on [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) now.